# Bash shell script did not pass the TRUE condition

Tags: linux, bash, shell

While the condition did not pass in the TRUE result. What's wrong with the syntax?

```
RESULT="Exited (0) Less than a second ago"
if [ "$RESULT" = "Exited (0) Less than a second ago" || "$RESULT" = "Stop" ]
then
    echo 'exited'
elif [ "$RESULT" = *"Up"* ]
then
    echo 'stopped and exited'
else
    echo 'Docker already removed'
fi
```

Comment: Add a shebang (#!/bin/bash) as first line, copy-paste your code in [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and fix the syntax errors.

Comment: See [Bash Pitfall #6: `[ "$foo" = bar && "$bar" = foo ]`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls?highlight=%28errexit%29#A.5B_.22.24foo.22_.3D_bar_.26.26_.22.24bar.22_.3D_foo_.5D) (it's about `&&`, but `||` works exactly the same).

Comment: Hi, @RenaudPacalet Thank you for your reply. I added (#!/bin/bash) before the script then the same result did not pass the TRUE condition.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks for sharing the article. I'll check.

Comment: You should have gotten an error message (_bash: [: missing ']'_) . See `man test` for how the test command works. Better (and less error prone), use the  `[[ ... ]]` construct instead of the `[` command.

Comment: I suggested to add a shebang such that shellcheck knows which shell you use. So I repeat: copy-paste your code in shellcheck and fix the errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following script works properly based on the provided conditions.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

RESULT="Exited (0) Less than a second ago"


if [ "$RESULT" = "Exited (0) Less than a second ago" ] || [ "$RESULT" = "Stop" ]; then
    echo 'exited'
elif [ "$RESULT" = "Up" ]; then
    echo 'stopped and exited'
else
    echo 'Docker already removed'
fi
```

I changed the parameter "-o" to "[ ] || [ ]" after being informed by [tjm3772](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19271565/tjm3772) that the "-o" option is obsolete in [POSIX 2017](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).

Comment: Hi, @cforler Thank you for your suggestion I remove the OR "||" and replace the "-o" instead then it works as expected.

Comment: Note that `-o` is obsolete in POSIX and has undefined behavior in more complex tests. The more reliable solution in a POSIX shell is to use multiple tests, e.g. `[ a = b ] || [ c = d ]`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the accepted answer is using POSIX `sh`, an alternative is to use a `case` statement.

```
#!/bin/sh

RESULT="Exited (0) Less than a second ago"

case "$RESULT" in
   "Exited (0) Less than a second ago"|"STOP")
      echo exited;;
   "Up") 
      echo 'stopped and exited';;
    *) 
     echo 'Docker already removed';;
esac
```

---

- See [Case conditional Construct](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05)
- See `help case`